# How do you create a QR codes that creates an email that includes pre-drafted information?

Tags: email

A friend wants to create a QR code that sends an e-mail with the subject line and body of the e-mail pre-drafted. Can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. You can use for example [this free web service](http://www.mobile-barcodes.com/qr-code-generator/) (select "email" tab).

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting this thread for anyone still interested.

The answer above is perfectly valid if you are looking at creating a specific QR code only once.

If you are looking at doing this programmatically, you might be better off using some sort of QR-encoding library for whatever programming language you use, and use the MATMSG syntax to generate this on the fly.

See the reference here: http://www.labnol.org/internet/email-with-qr-code/19610/

Specifically, the syntax is

```
MATMSG:TO:

john@example.com;

SUB:

Subject here

BODY:

Message body here
;;
```

You can also use the normal HTML *mailto* notation if that makes it easier for you.

I hope this helps!